# How to make a Sigmoid function work on tensors

Tags: python, numpy, sigmoid

I am trying to build a logistic regression model and I implemented a sigmoid function from scratch using python. It works on regular integers and floats but does not work on individual values in tensors.

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))
```

> X

```
array([[2.9e+01, 5.6e+04],
       [6.4e+01, 8.9e+04],
       [3.3e+01, 1.7e+04],
       [4.5e+01, 9.4e+04],
       [2.4e+01, 2.6e+04],
       [5.5e+01, 2.4e+04],
       [3.5e+01, 5.2e+04],
       [5.7e+01, 6.5e+04],
       [4.5e+01, 3.2e+04],
       [5.2e+01, 7.5e+04],
       [6.2e+01, 3.1e+04]])
```

> sigmoid(X)

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the numbers in your array are too large, so `np.exp(large negative number)` is very *very* small. Example, your smallest number is 24 and `np.exp(-24)` is 3.775134544279098**e-11**. So 1 / (1 + very small number) ≈ 1. For your largest number 9400, the result is 0.0.

If you divided your list by a 100 or so, then you start seeing reasonable results:

```py
1/(1 + np.exp(-a/100))  # a is your array

# output:
array([[0.57199613, 1.        ],
       [0.65475346, 1.        ],
       [0.58175938, 1.        ],
       [0.61063923, 1.        ],
       [0.55971365, 1.        ],
       [0.63413559, 1.        ],
       [0.58661758, 1.        ],
       [0.63876318, 1.        ],
       [0.61063923, 1.        ],
       [0.62714777, 1.        ],
       [0.65021855, 1.        ]])
```

So consider scaling your numbers from 0 to 1 or 0 to 3 so that the result of the sigmoid function is *useful*.

For example `sigmoid(a/[100, 100_000])` gives:

```
array([[0.57199613, 0.63645254],
       [0.65475346, 0.70889017],
       [0.58175938, 0.54239794],
       [0.61063923, 0.71909966],
       [0.55971365, 0.56463629],
       [0.63413559, 0.55971365],
       [0.58661758, 0.62714777],
       [0.63876318, 0.65701046],
       [0.61063923, 0.57932425],
       [0.62714777, 0.6791787 ],
       [0.65021855, 0.57688526]])
```

Using a scaler like those in `sklearn`:

```py
x = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(a).transform(a)  # don't do it like this
sigmoid(x)

# output:
array([[0.22005356, 0.5481681 ],
       [0.80397984, 0.81288489],
       [0.27698944, 0.21177685],
       [0.48957277, 0.8405247 ],
       [0.16141442, 0.27560685],
       [0.6732804 , 0.26044295],
       [0.30863906, 0.50966239],
       [0.70599565, 0.63208245],
       [0.48957277, 0.32422274],
       [0.62096054, 0.71660935],
       [0.77875086, 0.31581168]])
```